# Using flexbox to replace fixed and absolute positioning

Tags: html, css

I'm using flexbox to create a simple header, hero image with caption and footer.

As you can see from my snippet, the header is fixed and the hero image scrolls underneath.

Is there a way to achieve my layout without fixed or absolute positioning? I'm relatively new to flexbox and and haven't come across a solution.

For the image, I could use the background property, but I'd like to maintain what I have to easily implement img srcset and an alt tag.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

/* Flexbox */
.main-navigation,
.main-navigation ul,
.hero {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.main-navigation {
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
}

/* Site header */
.site-header {
  position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 z-index: 9999; /* Always on top */
 width: 100%; /* Must have width for flex */
  padding: 24px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #021928;
}

/* Hero */
.hero {
 position: relative; /* For image */
 height: 100vh; /* Fill viewport */
  justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}

.hero img {
  position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: -1; /* Send image to back */
 height: 100vh;
 object-fit: cover;
 object-position: bottom;
}

/* Cosmetic */
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
 margin-right: 12px;
}

li:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}

a,
a:visited,
a:focus,
a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

p {
  padding: 24px;
}

.caption {
  padding: 0;
}


h1 {
  margin: 0 0 12px;
}

.logo {
  margin: 0;
}

.caption {
  max-width: 600px;
 text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.site-footer {
  padding: 24px;
  background-color: #021928;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="site-header">
  
  <nav class="main-navigation">
    <h1 class="logo">Logo</h1>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item One</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item Three</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  
</div><!-- .site-header -->

<div class="hero">
  
  <div class="caption">  
    <h1>Title goes here</h1>
    <p class="caption">And a caption</p>
  </div>

  <img src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/660/cpsprodpb/3963/production/_103119641_7623dbe4-9ef2-4108-a2f1-a745d0640c53.jpg" alt="Kittens">

</div><!-- .hero -->

<div class="main">
  <p>Main page content</p>
</div><!-- .main -->

<div class="site-footer">
  <span>Some information about stuff</span>
</div><!-- .site-footer -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither the fixed position of the header nor the positioning of the background image is achievable with flexbox.

You can replace `fixed` with `sticky`. This fixes the offset of the background image for `.hero` (`sticky` effects the flow of elements). This also allows us to drop the `width` attribute which is incorrectly set to `width: 100%` (should be `width: calc(100% - 48px)`) and thus fix so that the entire header is visible.

I think you should use `background-image`. I agree with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4216214/3755425) post stating you don't need an alt for a background image. And there's decent support for [the image-set css property](https://caniuse.com/#search=image-set) (although I don't have experience with this property myself).

https://codepen.io/a-morn/pen/xvdVZm

Edit: I recommend [Flexbox Zombies](http://flexboxzombies.com/p/flexbox-zombies) if you want to learn more about what flexbox can and can't do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I like position: sticky and your method for the background image.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the header to be "sticky" the only way is to make it `position:fixed`. In order to to push the rest of the content down, you need to know the headers `height`. Then you set a `margin-top` to your `#hero`.